# How to fix seaborn heatmap color mapping when values are in wide range

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, colormap

I have a dataframe with 6 unique values in range(0-9). I want to assign specif color to each value but mapping is not working for me.

This is how my dataframe looks like:

[image: Data Frame]

```
cmap_new = {0: '#faf5f5', 1: '#ff0303', 6: '#1f78b4', 7: '#b2df8a', 8: '#33a02c', 9: '#fb9a99'}
cmap = ListedColormap([cmap_new[i] for i in cmap_new.keys()])
ax = sns.heatmap(data=tmp_df, cmap=cmap, yticklabels=True, xticklabels=False,linewidths=1,square=True,annot=True)
```

My plot looks like this:

[image]

In my data, though I dont have values [2-5], they are assigned a color. I want to fix this problem and assign colors only to keys in the cmap_new dictionary.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BoundaryNorm` to assign a color to each of the values used. An extra value is needed, as 7 boundaries define 6 color regions. In order to get a nice colorbar, the ticks can be moved to the centers of each region.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import pandas as pd

cmap_new = {0: '#faf5f5', 1: '#ff0303', 6: '#1f78b4', 7: '#b2df8a', 8: '#33a02c', 9: '#fb9a99'}
keys = sorted(cmap_new.keys())
keys += [max(keys) + 1]
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(keys, size=(8, 7)),
                      index=['Zoros', 'Lyra', 'Elara', 'Drakor', 'Astra', 'Mystalin', 'Terra', 'Vora'])
cmap = ListedColormap([cmap_new[k] for k in keys[:-1]])
norm = BoundaryNorm(keys, ncolors=len(keys) - 1)
ax = sns.heatmap(data=tmp_df, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                 yticklabels=True, xticklabels=False, linewidths=1, square=True, annot=True)
ax.collections[0].colorbar.set_ticks([(k1 + k2) / 2 for k1, k2 in zip(keys[:-1], keys[1:])], labels=keys[:-1])
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn heatmap with specific colors for non-successive values]